# schedule crontab in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, cron

I have created a cronjob task list in a cron.txt file. This file contains list of cron jobs to be executed.

```
From this, consider  job A should be run 3 times every day,
         * job B should be run 4 times in a week 
         * job C should be run 8 or 9 times in a month.
```

I have already created a crontab for this to execute in every minute. It gives more load to the server. How to reduce the load for the server? [**Because events will be scheduled 2 or 3 times in a day].
How to schedule a dynamic crontab for this, in Linux Ubuntu?

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to schedule a cron in LINUX, based on the value retrieved from the MySQL DB instead of running a crontab in every minute or every hour ?

(Can we schedule a crontab dynamically based on the value retrieved from MySQL DB?)

Else,

We will run a crontab every day midnight to get the schedule times and as per the schedule times, we can run a crontab.

[Running a cron in every minute or every hour also some unnecessary loading to the server.]

Comment: What is it that makes you think that putting a file named "crontab_test.txt" in your home directory constitutes setting up a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the man page on `crontab` : (e.g. `man crontab`)

To edit a crontab, you need to call `crontab -e`. This will open the editor defined in the `EDITOR` environment variable.

`crontab -l` will list currently set crontabs. But this does not necessarily mean that the crontab is valid.

Comment: Thanks buddy, now it is working fine for me.    When editing the crontab file with linux command and when saving the file it is stored on the temp folder by default, this is the reason I got struck. Then, I have created cron.txt file at home folder and run the cron file using crontab command now it is working great. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 2):

Putting crontab-formatted text into arbitrarily-named files does not constitute setting up a cron job. Your cron configuration is stored in a system-owned file in a system-owned location. Use the command `crontab -e` to edit your crontab, or `crontab -l` to display the current crontab.